# VBA - Value of an option button in a frame (within an Excel sheet)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I'm having problems with shapes, frames and option buttons... I'm a total newbie, I've never used them. I just put several option buttons on an Excel sheet (Using the FORM toolbox).

I'm trying to check whether my optionbutton is filled or not. So far, I've done the following :

```
Sub SX_EXTERNE()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim ConBut As Shape
Dim Answer As String

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Externe")

For Each ConBut In Ws.Shapes
    If ConBut.Type = msoFormControl Then
        If ConBut.FormControlType = xlOptionButton Then
            If ConBut.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
                 Answer = ConBut.Name
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next ConBut

MsgBox Answer

End Sub
```

My problem is I do not know how to check only in a selected frame (i.e. "Conges_generaux" for my example):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could you please give me a hint? I've seen many subjects about that but many of them treat of ActiveXControls... I don't even know the difference.

Thanks

Comment: Is that a Frame or a Group Box?

Comment: Hi Siddharth Rout, just updated my post with a picture. I think it's a group box. EDIT: Thanks for your help on the calendar thing using a Userform. Eventually I'm not gonna use a "date picking system" but I'm saving this link for later :)

Comment: So it is a group box. Now GroupBox doesn't behave like an ActiveX Frame.Are there other option buttons besides these two as well. Are you able to "check" both options on?

Comment: Alright. Could you pls explain what's the difference between ActiveXControls and other controls? What would you recommend me to use on my example? I do have other group boxes (3). EDIT: See the second edit, I've added another screenshot.

Comment: In an ActiveX Frame, if you have 2 or more checkboxes then you can "Check" only one of them. Here GroupBoxes will not play the same role. If you have 10 checkboxes then you will be able to "check" all of them. One option that you can do is group the Groupbox and their checkboxes together and then in the code check if the checkbox is part of a group

Comment: Alright, that's what I've done. Because I want only one answer in each groupBox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146241/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-jean-fic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick way

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim optBtn As OptionButton

    For Each optBtn In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons
        If optBtn.Value = 1 Then
           Debug.Print optBtn.Name
           Debug.Print optBtn.GroupBox.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So in your code change `Dim ConBut As Shape` to `Dim ConBut As OptionButton`. Feel free to put relevant checks and store it in the relevant `answer` variable :)

Comment: Thanks for your time Siddharth you're awesome! I also added this "If optBtn.GroupBox.Name = "Conges_generaux" Then" to my code. Btw, the second code does not work since Conbut is an OptionButton, you cannot search in Each Conbut in Ws.SHAPES.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I've groupped my option buttons and now it does not work anymore... When i'm reading the code line by line, it just skips the line "For each optBtn in Ws.OptionButtons"... Any idea? Maybe it is represented as a shape now since I've merged them? Do I need to create a new post for that? Thanks :)