# VBA - For Each, OptionButtons and Groups

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I'd like to unactivate my option buttons but since I've grouped them with altogether my code won't work anymore.

So far I have this :

```
Sub Clean_sheet()
Dim Ws as Worksheet
Dim optBtn As OptionButton
Dim m As Byte

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Externe")

    For Each optBtn In Ws.OptionButtons
        optBtn.Value = -4146
    Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

it just skips the part "For each optBtn in...". I don't use activexControls.

My groups look like this :

[image]

[image]

[I've already been helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454481/vba-value-of-an-option-button-in-a-frame-within-an-excel-sheet/44455428?noredirect=1#comment75911858_44455428) but since I grouped my forms it does not work anymore :(.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will deselect all options in group "GPE_M1":

```
Dim Group_Frame As Shape
Dim Group_Item As Shape

    Set Group_Frame = ws.Shapes("GPE_M1")  'top frame 

    For Each Group_Item In Group_Frame.GroupItems
        If Group_Item.FormControlType = xlOptionButton Then 
           Group_Item.ControlFormat.Value = -4146
        End if
    Next Group_Item
```

Comment: Thanks RADO that's great. I adapted it a bit for the reste of my code. Do you have any tutorial about shapes, option buttons and so on, please? I totally suck at this!